# How can I create a resource in Rails/SQL that belongs_to many different resources but does not require a foreign id for all of them?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

Here is my recurring payment model. I want it to optionally belong to each of the included resources, but to allow creation with only one parent resource. I tried setting the default for each foreign key to 0, but I still get an error when I try to create instances saying "bank account must exist", "investment must exist", etc. I am sure there must be a way to accomplish this, but I cannot see how? *Edit: I solved this by defaulting the foreign id's to 1 instead of 0, since this will just be seed data anyway, but I would still love to know if anyone has a better solution!

```
class RecurringPayment < ApplicationRecord 
belongs_to :bank_account 
belongs_to :credit_card 
belongs_to :investment 
belongs_to :loan  

 def bank_account_name 
  self.try(:bank_account).try(:name)
end

def bank_account_name=(name)
bank_account = BankAccount.find_by(name: name)
if bank_account
  self.bank_account = bank_account 
end
end 

def credit_card_provider
 self.try(:credit_card).try(:provider)
end

def credit_card_provider=(provider)
credit_card = CreditCard.find_by(provider: provider) 
if credit_card
  self.credit_card = credit_card 
end
end  

def investment_name
self.try(:investment).try(:name)
end

def investment_name=(name)
 investment = Investment.find_by(name: name)
 if investment 
  self.investment = investment
  end
end   

def loan_name
  self.try(:loan).try(:name)
end

def loan_name=(name)
loan = Loan.find_by(name: name) 
if loan
  self.loan = loan 
end
end   
end
```

Here is the schema:

```
create_table "recurring_payments", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string "source"
t.boolean "status"
t.date "pay_date"
t.integer "pay_amount"
t.integer "duration"
t.integer "bank_account_id", default: 0
t.integer "credit_card_id", default: 0
t.integer "loan_id", default: 0
t.integer "investment_id", default: 0
t.datetime "created_at", null: false
t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
t.integer "payment_frequency"
end
```

Comment: I haven't tested this, so I'm just spitballing here, but I'm pretty sure you'll get what you want by changing those `default: 0` flags to `null: true`.

Comment: Just tried that syntax, but it doesn't seem to change the schema at all. Seems like null defaults to true, which is why it is strange to me that I am having this issue at all. I think it must have something to do with the way I specified the relationship in the model, but I'm definitely not sure.

Comment: Maybe you're wanting a polymorphic association? http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Rails 5, belongs_to associations are required by default.
You can change this behavior in a config file, by adding:

```
Rails.application.config.active_record.belongs_to_required_by_default = false
```

Or in a specific class:

```
class RecurringPayment < ApplicationRecord 
  belongs_to :bank_account, optional: true
  belongs_to :credit_card, optional: true
  belongs_to :investment, optional: true
  belongs_to :loan, optional: true
end
```

In your code you should always check before using the association model, as it may not exist.

Check section 4.20 in this documentation: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html

Comment: Thank you! Thats very helpful. I knew I didnt remember this behavior from Rails 4.2 lol.